# Remove Nth item from a variable list of lists

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to figure out a Pythonic way to remove the Nth item from a variable list of lists.

For example, how would I remove the last item from lists with variable depths in one method, one liner, something pretty?

```
example1 = [
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6]
    ]
]

expected_output_1 = [
    [
        [1,2],
        [4,5]
    ]
]

example2 = [
    [
        [
            [
                [1,2,3],
                [4,5,6]
            ]
         ]
    ]
]

expected_output_2 = [
    [
        [
            [
                [1,2],
                [4,5]
            ]
         ]
    ]
]
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? It might be possible to do this with a one-liner, but I doubt it'd be elegant. First you need to figure out how deep the nesting is. And then it's easy to do the deletions at the nominated positions.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a one-liner. I am just after a very elegant way to do this. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: Are you using `numpy` at all in your program? `np.array(example1)[...,:-1]` grabs all elements up to the last in the deepest dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a one-liner that would work, as getting to the deepest list is a bit tricky. The bottom function below removes the nt'h element as long as the input is at least a list of lists (use `n=-1` to remove the last element).

```
from collections import Sequence
from itertools import chain, count

def depth(seq):
    for level in count():
        if not seq:
            return level
        seq = list(chain.from_iterable(s for s in seq if isinstance(s, Sequence)))

def remove_nth_from_deepest_list(lst, n):
    d = depth(lst)
    for _ in range(d - 2):
        lst = lst[0]
    for sublist in lst:
        del sublist[n]
    for _ in range(d - 2):
        lst = [lst]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For list in example1:
    list = list.del(len((list)-1))
```

I can't guarantee that works.

Comment: And for example2 you would just go one loop deeper

Comment: First off, `list` is a keyword in Python; you shouldn't assign it as a variable name. Second, lists don't have a `.del()` method; `del` is a Python keyword that expects a statement; what you mean to do AFAICT is `del list[len(list)-1]`. Also your phone capitalized `For`. Then this says `len((list)-1)` which is trying to subtract one from a list (unsupported operand `-` for `int` and`list`) and also trying to find the `len` of an integer; obviously you meant `len(list)-1`. Finally, even with all of these corrections; this doesn't work. Moral of the story...maybe don't answer on your phone lol

Answer (score 0):

> If you would like to understand it step by step in a simple way this
>   is how it works

.**This was just because the person wanted a explanation its not a good practice tough**

```
    for x in l: #looping first time
        for x1 in x: #looping to flatten
            for x2 in x1: #looping again to flatten the set
                for x3 in x2: #last loop to get a proper set of list
                    del x3[len(x3)-1] # deleting the last one by subtracting with length
                    print(x3) # printing result
```

> Expected output for l = [[[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]]]
>
> > [1, 2] [4, 5]

Answer (score 0):

First, we use a recursive function to deterine how deeply a list is nested, then we use simple looping to get down to the level we want to trim, using slice assignment to remove the last item from each innermost sublist.

```
example0 = [[1, 2, 3]]

example1 = [
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6]
    ]
]

example2 = [
    [
        [
            [
                [1,2,3],
                [4,5,6]
            ]
         ]
    ]
]

def list_depth(seq, depth=0):
    if isinstance(seq, list):
        return list_depth(seq[0], depth + 1)
    return depth

for seq in (example0, example1, example2):
    print('original:', seq)
    t = seq
    for i in range(list_depth(seq) - 2):
        t = t[0]
    t[:] = [u[:-1] for u in t]
    print('trimmed: ', seq, '\n')
```

**output**

```
original: [[1, 2, 3]]
trimmed:  [[1, 2]] 

original: [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
trimmed:  [[[1, 2], [4, 5]]] 

original: [[[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]]]
trimmed:  [[[[[1, 2], [4, 5]]]]]
```